# Debian disable the internal mail completely

Tags: debian

I discovered recently that my server has been attempting to send 1000 emails a day (my limit) because of the internal mail system, where it'd be attempting to send actual emails to @ rather then using the internal `mail` that linux has.

Since I don't use this feature at all, how can I completely (either system-wide or per-user) disable this internal `mail` system to prevent it from happening?

Running Debian 8 with EXIM4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by configuring EXIM4 as an `internet site` rather than `smart host; no local mail` (in the steps from `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`)

As well as removing `localhost` from the `destinations for which mail is accepted`

Answer (score 2):

Debian comes by default with exim mail server, you can configure how the mailserver should work with the command

```
dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

if you don't want the server to send remote emails you can choose the setting

```
local delivery only; not on a network
```

Comment: will this allow functions such as PHPMailer continue to function? it sounds like the opposite (and I'm indeed using exim)

Comment: I believe PHPMailer allows you to send mails without a local smtp server so it should still work, unless you send your mail through the local exim mail server.
the local `mail` also uses exim so if you just want the application `mail` to be gone you could just uninstall it, it's found in the package mailutils, so a apt-get remove mailutils should remove the `mail` app.

Comment: My hosting provider requires my VPS to mail via their mail servers, so I'm indeed using a local exim mail server to achieve that. I tried removing `mailutils`, but apparently that package isn't installed

Comment: I also just now tried removing `bsd-mailx` but that doesn't seem to have helped either

Answer (score 0):

ok finally I just used sysv-rc-conf, install with apt-get, to disable the exim4 daemon on my system at all levels, and I did sudo service exim4 stop to kill it in the current environment.

for sysv-rf-conf, spacebar to select, q to exit